# How do I pass an object to HttpClient.PostAsync and serialize as a JSON body?

Tags: c#, json, dotnet-httpclient

I'm using `System.Net.Http`, I found several examples on the web. I managed to create this code for make a `POST` request:

```
public static string POST(string resource, string token)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUri);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("token", token);

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
             new KeyValuePair<string, string>("", "")
        });

        var result = client.PostAsync("", content).Result;
        string resultContent = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        return resultContent;
    }
 }
```

all working fine. But suppose that I want pass a third param to the `POST` method, a param called `data`. The data param is an object like this:

```
object data = new
{
    name = "Foo",
    category = "article"
};
```

how can I do that without create the `KeyValuePair`? My php `RestAPI` wait a json input, so the `FormUrlEncodedContent` should send the `raw` json correctly. But how can I do this with `Microsoft.Net.Http`? Thanks.

Comment: If I understand your question, you want to send JSON content instead of form encoded content right (and by extension you want your anonymous type to be serialized as JSON into that content)?

Comment: @CodingGorilla yes is an anonymous type.

Comment: As a side note for future readers, do not use a `using` for the `HttpClient`. https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Comment: Note from Microsoft why `using` should not be used: `HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once and reused throughout the life of an application. The following conditions can result in SocketException errors:

Creating a new HttpClient instance per request.
Server under heavy load.
Creating a new HttpClient instance per request can exhaust the available sockets.` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

Comment: Side note: `.Result` will deadlock in any environment that has a synchronization context.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine right, coder should perhaps look into `ConfigureAwait(false)` to negate that...

Comment: If using HttpServer/HttpClient for unit testing a webapi application, it is VERY important to serialize first, because if you don't, it skips the deserializer for all unit tests. That's fine, unless you do something special in the deserializer...

Answer (score 214, accepted):

**Update:** If you're using .NET 5 or newer, use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36625881/how-do-i-pass-an-object-to-httpclient-postasync-and-serialize-as-a-json-body#65909932).

The straight up answer to your question is: No.  The signature for the [`PostAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138190(v=vs.118).aspx) method is as follows:

> public Task PostAsync(Uri requestUri, HttpContent content)

So, while you can pass an `object` to `PostAsync` it must be of type `HttpContent` and your anonymous type does not meet that criteria.

However, there are ways to accomplish what you want to accomplish.  First, you will need to serialize your anonymous type to JSON, the most common tool for this is [Json.NET](http://www.json.net).  And the code for this is pretty trivial:

```
var myContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
```

Next, you will need to construct a content object to send this data, I will use a `ByteArrayContent` object, but you could use or create a different type if you wanted.

```
var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myContent);
var byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);
```

Next, you want to set the content type to let the API know this is JSON.

```
byteContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
```

Then you can send your request very similar to your previous example with the form content:

```
var result = client.PostAsync("", byteContent).Result
```

On a side note, calling the `.Result` property like you're doing here can have some [bad side effects](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/01/13/10115163.aspx) such as dead locking, so you want to be careful with this.

Comment: Okay it's very clear. Thanks for this answer. Just a question: when a `POST, PUT, DELETE` is performed, usually the API return `TRUE`, I declared the method as `string`, but when I do: `return result;` I get: `Can't Convert HttpResponseMessage in string`, should I change the method declaration? I need the string response 'cause I'll need to deserialize it after in other class method.

Comment: If you need to deserialize the body of the response, then returning the string the way you have in your question (using `result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`) is probably just fine.  Depending on your application structure, it might be better to return the `Content` object directly if you need to inspect the headers to determine what the conent type is (e.g. XML or JSON).  But if you **know** it's always going to return JSON (or some other format) then just returning the response body as a string should be ok.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but if do you need to do this if the data is of type `StringContent` ?

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but you can pass a `StringContent` directly to `PostAsync` since it derives from `HttpContent`.

Comment: @CodingGorilla, that *was* what I was asking. Thank you :)

Comment: In more recent versions of .Net, there is now a much simpler way to achieve what OP wants. Since this is the accepted (and highest voted answer), please consider an edit that points new readers towards the [answer about PostAsJsonAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66036888/326110) by @charles-thayer

Answer (score 114):

## New .NET 5+ Solution:

In .NET 5, a new class has been introduced called `JsonContent`, which derives from `HttpContent`. [See in Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.jsoncontent?view=net-5.0)

This class contains a static method called `Create()`, which takes any arbitrary object as a parameter, and as the name implies returns an instance of `JsonContent`, which you can then pass as an argument to the `PostAsync` method.

Usage:

```
var obj = new
{
    foo = "Hello",
    bar = "World",
};

JsonContent content = JsonContent.Create(obj);

await client.PostAsync("https://...", content);
```

**Even better**, you can actually use `HttpClient`'s new `PostAsJsonAsync` extension method to make this as concise as possible — see [the docs for this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.httpclientjsonextensions.postasjsonasync?view=net-5.0).
Usage:

```
var obj = new
{
    foo = "Hello",
    bar = "World",
};
await client.PostAsJsonAsync("https://...", obj);
```

Comment: This creates an ObjectContent<T> which gets passed directly to the webapi. Because it is not serialized, it skips the Formatters configured in the webapi to deserialize.

Comment: @Brain2000 What is the "web API"? You mean the HTTP client? And what do "formatters" refer to in the context?

Comment: the WebAPI and HttpClient/Server use the same owin stack. The config.Formatters tell how to serialize/deserialize things that need to be. In our case, we use the deserializer to know which fields are included so when performing a PUT, only those fields are updated. That allows one to set nulls in a PUT.

Answer (score 98):

You need to pass your data in the request body as a raw string rather than `FormUrlEncodedContent`. One way to do so is to serialize it into a JSON string:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data); // or JsonSerializer.Serialize if using System.Text.Json
```

Now, all you need to do is pass the `StringContent` instance to the `PostAsync` method:

```
var stringContent = new StringContent(json, UnicodeEncoding.UTF8, "application/json"); // use MediaTypeNames.Application.Json in Core 3.0+ and Standard 2.1+

var client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, stringContent);
```

Comment: What is `stringContent`? In my case `stringContent` value is `"\"\""`. Is this correct value?

Comment: is it possible to obtain the string result in vb from your c# code? i found out it's quite similar....

Answer (score 58):

A simple solution is to use `Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.2 Client` from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnet.webapi.client/).

Then you can simply do this and it'll serialize the object to JSON and set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json; charset=utf-8`:

```
var data = new
{
    name = "Foo",
    category = "article"
};

var client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUri);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("token", token);
var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("", data);
```

Comment: definitely PostAsJsonAsync is there to use

Comment: Would be nice if it had a corresponding PatchAsJsonAsync too.

Answer (score 33):

There's now a simpler way with `.NET Standard` or `.NET Core`:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, myRequestObject, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
```

**NOTE:** In order to use the `JsonMediaTypeFormatter` class, you will need to install the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` NuGet package, which can be installed directly, or via another such as `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`.

Using this signature of `HttpClient.PostAsync`, you can pass in any object and the `JsonMediaTypeFormatter` will automatically take care of serialization etc.

With the response, you can use `HttpContent.ReadAsAsync<T>` to deserialize the response content to the type that you are expecting:

```
var responseObject = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<MyResponseType>();
```

Comment: what version of .net is this using? My version can't find "Formatting" in the System.Net.Http namespace

Comment: @Programmatic You need to be using `.NET Standard` or `.NET Core`, as I mentioned. Maybe you're using `.NET Framework`?

In my project, the JsonMediaTypeFormatter is being loaded from here:

C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnet.webapi.client\5.2.6\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll

Comment: @Programmatic If you're already using one of those project types, it might be that you need to add an extra NuGet package. I forget exactly which were included automatically for me.

In my case, it was included as part of the Microsoft.AspNetCore.App NuGet package.

Comment: I was using .NET Core,  but I don't think I my solution was set to use the latest version of the c# language. I updated and it worked. Thank you

Comment: @Programmatic You're welcome. I'm glad to hear you got it working! I've added a note to my answer about the NuGet package.

Answer (score 23):

@arad good point.  In fact I just found this extension method (.NET 5.0):

`PostAsJsonAsync<TValue>(HttpClient, String, TValue, CancellationToken)`

from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.httpclientjsonextensions.postasjsonasync?view=net-5.0

So one can now:

```
var data = new { foo = "Hello"; bar = 42; };
var response = await _Client.PostAsJsonAsync(_Uri, data, cancellationToken);
```

Comment: In 2022, this is now the most correct solution and must be upvoted like the dickens

Answer (score 5):

You have two options depending on which framework are you coding, you could just do `JsonContent.Create(yourObject);` if you are on .Net 5

or create and extension method and call it on your object:

```
public static StringContent GetStringContent(this object obj)
{
    var jsonContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
    var contentString = new StringContent(jsonContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    contentString.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

    return contentString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static async Task<string> Post(string param, string code, string subject, string description)
    {
        object mydata = new
        {
            code = code,
            subject = subject,
            description = description
        };
        var myContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mydata);
        var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myContent);
        var byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);
        byteContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (HttpResponseMessage res = await client.PostAsync(baseURL + param, byteContent))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Nico", res);
                using (HttpContent content = res.Content)
                {
                    string data = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    if (data != null) { return data; }
                }
            }
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
```

in my other form

```
private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //POST
        {
            string param = "subject";
            string code = txtCode.Text; //NC101
            string subject = txtSubject.Text;
            string description = txtDescription.Text;
            var res = await RESTHelper.Post(param, code, subject, description);
            txtRes.Text = res;
        }
```