# How to receive response from server in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have created an HTTP Client that sends data to my server. This data will query my server that will return a JSON object. How can I receive the JSON Object response from my server and insert it into my database?

The code below will send a **ContactID** to my server and my server will return a JSON Object How can I get the JSON Object from my server? What will I add to my code? I have added

```
var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

but I don't know how to proceed.

```
try
        {
            var db = DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteDB>();
            var conn = db.GetConnection();

            var sql = "SELECT * FROM tblUser WHERE ContactID = '" + contact + "'";
            var getUser = conn.QueryAsync<UserTable>(sql);
            var resultCount = getUser.Result.Count;

            //Check if the user has been sync
            if (resultCount < 1)
            {
                try
                {
                    syncStatus.Text = "Syncing user to server...";

                    var link = Constants.requestUrl + "Host=" + host + "&Database=" + database + "&Contact=" + contact + "&Request=8qApc8";
                    string contentType = "application/json";
                    JObject json = new JObject
                    {
                        { "ContactID", contact }
                    };

                    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                    var response = await client.PostAsync(link, new StringContent(json.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, contentType));
                    var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        var userresult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<UserData>>(content);
                        var count = userresult.Count;

                        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                syncStatus.Text = "Syncing user to server...";

                                var item = userresult[i];
                                var contactID = item.ContactID;
                                var userID = item.UserID;
                                var userPassword = item.UserPassword;
                                var userType = item.UserType;
                                var userStatus = item.UserStatus;
                                var lastSync = item.LastSync;
                                var serverUpdate = item.ServerUpdate;
                                var mobileUpdate = item.MobileUpdate;

                                var user = new UserTable
                                {
                                    ContactID = Convert.ToInt32(contactID),
                                    UserID = userID,
                                    UserPassword = userPassword,
                                    UserType = userType,
                                    UserStatus = userStatus,
                                    LastSync = lastSync,
                                    ServerUpdate = serverUpdate,
                                    MobileUpdate = mobileUpdate
                                };

                                await conn.InsertAsync(user);
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                Console.Write("Syncing user error " + ex.Message);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.Write("Syncing User Error " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
```

My PHP code will query my database with the **ContactID** received from **Xamarin HTTP Client**.

```
$json_str = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $json_obj = json_decode($json_str);

    $ContactID = $json_obj->ContactID;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblUser WHERE ContactID = '$ContactID'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($count > 0){
        while ($row = @mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $decr = CryptRC4(FromHexDump($row['UserPassword']), $key);

            $ar[] = array(
                'ContactID' => $row['ContactID'],
                'UserID' => $row['UserID'],
                'UserPassword' => $decr,
                'UserType' => $row['UserType'],
                'UserStatus' => $row['UserStatus'],
                'LastSync' => $sync,
                'ServerUpdate' => $row['ServerUpdate'],
                'MobileUpdate' => $row['MobileUpdate']
            );

            print json_encode($ar);

            //Update LastSync DateTime
            $sql = "UPDATE tblUser SET LastSync = '$sync' WHERE ContactID = '$ContactID'";
            mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Last statement in your example above gives list of json objects in string format.

```
var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

You need to convert that back to list of objects. To let your project know about definition of the object, create a plain class with public properties (Something like below)

```
public class UserLog
{
    public int ContactId { get; set; }
    public string Log { get; set; }
    public DateTime LogDate { get; set; }
}
```

Add **Newtonsoft.Json** (by James Newton-King) Nuget package to your project so that you can work with json.

To convert content of the variable 'data' into list of UserLog objects, write code like

```
var list = NewtonsoftUtil<IList<UserLog>>.DeserializeObject(data);
```

(Add `using Newtonsoft.Json;` at top of the file)

Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: I will try this thank you I will let you know if this works

Comment: I updated my code I can get the response but cant seem to add the response in my local database

Comment: I cant count the var userresult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<UserData>>(content);
                        var count = userresult.Count;

Comment: Could you check what string do you get in the variable 'data'? Perhaps it is not as expected by the model class ('UserLog') you have defined. Please share the content of the varialble 'data'.

Answer (score 2):

The answers above missing one important point -> `efficiency`.

There is no need to allocate a string in memory, especially if your JSON is big. `Streams` can do much better then `string`s:

```
// Read the response as stream
var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

// Use the next method for deserialization
T DeserializeJsonFromStream<T>(Stream stream)
{
    if (stream == null || stream.CanRead == false)
        return default(T);

    using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
    using (var jtr = new JsonTextReader(sr))
    {
        var js = new JsonSerializer();
        return js.Deserialize<T>(jtr);
    }
}
```

P.S.: Code example is bases on [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json).
P.S.S.: There are many good articles on this topic, I could recommend to get familiar with the next [one](https://johnthiriet.com/efficient-api-calls/).

Comment: I updated my code please see I cant insert the data to my local database I can get the response but cant seem to insert the response to my local database. When I put a break when debugging, I cant count the number of responses @EvZ

Comment: Sounds like a totally different topic, please ask a new question with as many details as you can.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have done everything correctly. In other words, You're be able to sent your *contactID* and get back a json.

Let's say your json structure is something like:

`{"firstname" : "Doe",
"lastname" : "foo"
"age" : "27"}`

One possible way to retrieve the data is as below:

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;

//after PostAsync()
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    JObject jContent = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content);
    string firstName = (string)jContent.GetValue("firstname")
    string lastName = (string)jContent.GetValue("lastname");
    int age = (int)jContent.GetValue("age");
}
```

[Newtonsoft](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) is available on Nuget. you need to install it if you have not done so.

#### Improved solution

What if your json has many key/values pairs like  below:

`{  key1 : value1,
    key2 : value2,
    key3 : value3,
    ...
    key10 : value10}`

Then it is not a good idea by doing :

```cs
string foo1 = (string)jContent.GetValue("key1");
string foo2 = (string)jContent.GetValue("key2");
//...
string foo10 = (string)jContent.GetValue("key10");
```

To handle this case, you can create a class:

```cs
public class Foo
{
    public string Foo1 {get;set;}
    public string Foo2 {get;set;}
    //...
    public string Foo2 {get;set;}
}
```

Then, you can do as simple as below:

```cs
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Foo foo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(content);
}
```

The improved solution referecnced from [www.newtonsoft.com](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm). Go there and check out other ways of using the library.

Comment: I updated my code please see I cant insert the data to my local database I can get the response but cant seem to insert the response

Comment: I cant count the response inorder to insert it in my local database @Fuong

Comment: I added a try catch The error is Cannot convert string to datetime in LastSync

Comment: You **should not edit** your question into **a different question** than the original one. That makes it more difficult for others making sense the question and answers. Post another separate question if needed.