# Azure Custom Vision API returning unsupported media type for a JPG image url

Tags: c#, azure, computer-vision, azure-cognitive-services

I have built a small windows forms application just to play around with image recognition. I have trained a model, and I have built a windows forms application that takes my webcam image stream, uploads frames as JPG to an AWS S3 bucket, then passes the publicly readable URL to the Vision API to provide scoring on the tags.

If I pass the image via a POSTMAN call, it works fine, however within my code, I get the following error:

```
{StatusCode: 415, ReasonPhrase: 'Unsupported Media Type', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  apim-request-id: 8d5759e5-d32a-4ba2-8b54-16f3a3f1aa40
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
  x-content-type-options: nosniff
  Date: Thu, 20 Sep 2018 00:49:39 GMT
  Content-Length: 116
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
}}
```

According to the documentation:

> Response 415 Unsupported media type error. "Content-Type" does not
>   match the post content.
>
> For image URL, "Content-Type" should be application/json For binary
>   image data, "Content-Type" should be application/octet-stream

As you will see from my code below, I am setting the right content type. I will just post the function dealing with posting to the API as that's where the issue must be. Any help would be appreciated.

Firstly, the evidence that the call via POSTMAN works:

[image]
Here is my method that fails. You can see I set the right content type, and I'm using the same images for testing between my code and POSTMAN.

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Take a provided image url and return the Vision API results
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="url">a valid HTTP or HTTPS url containing a reference to a JPG image</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        static async Task<string> GenerateVisionResult(string url)
        {
            string visionResult = null; 

            try
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://southcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/customvision/v2.0/Prediction/3dd9e6c3-aac4-4da1-8c74-cd2d581d4782/url?iterationId=5c1b1548-98d7-45b0-a0e7-f397f35ffcd9");
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Prediction-Key", "<redacted for post on StackOverflow>");
                    var UrlBody = new UrlBody
                    {
                        Url = url
                    };

                    var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage
                    {
                        Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(UrlBody),Encoding.UTF8),
                        Method = HttpMethod.Post
                    };

                    HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await client.PostAsync(client.BaseAddress, httpRequestMessage.Content);
                    if (httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        visionResult = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        visionResult = httpResponse.StatusCode.ToString(); 
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); 
            }

            return visionResult;
        }
```

EDIT: I think I just realised my mistake, in the way I'm handling adding the url to the POST method. I'll report back once i've tried to fix it.

EDIT2: Nope. Still no dice. I thought maybe I wasn't seralising the URL object correctly, but i've tested and the content is as expected, just serialising the following object:

```
public class UrlBody
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If you do not receive any suggestions, you could use Fiddler to compare the message with Postman. Always a good tool to have.

Comment: Thanks Jamie. I find Fiddler difficult / intimidating to use, and need to spend more time to understand the output and how to configure it. I also just tested by embedding a known good JPG url from Google image search into my code, same result, same error.

Comment: I ran Fiddler. First error I can see is this: HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type
Content-Length: 116
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
apim-request-id: 49024a98-fed4-4b1f-bcdd-efeed5535ddd
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
x-content-type-options: nosniff
Date: Thu, 20 Sep 2018 01:28:10 GMT

{"code":"ErrorUnknown","message":"The request entity's media type 'text/plain' is not supported for this resource."}. Which is odd, because as you can see in my code I specify application/json.

Comment: You do not care about the response yet. Right now, look at the sent message, immediately before that. It will show what your POST.

Comment: This is where I start to get lost.. the captured event right before the 415 is just # Result Protocol Host URL Body Caching Content-Type Process Comments Custom 
11 200 HTTP Tunnel to southcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com:443 0   webcamrecognitiontest:14812

Comment: I have another suspicion that maybe my serialising the object to JSON to send, may be causing the post method to think it's text/plain, not application/json concent (despite setting the header). This isn't my area of expertise, but there is literature that suggests converting the json to a byte array and then to HttpContent to make it usable. I will give that a shot. (Reading from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36625881/how-do-i-pass-an-object-to-httpclient-postasync-and-serialize-as-a-json-body)

Comment: In Fiddler - Tools | Options | HTTPS tab | Decrypt HTTPS Traffic should be enabled. Restart Fiddler, run your test again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Jamie for his help with Fiddler, but I found the issue. You can't pass the content to the POST method the way I have in my original code. You have to convert the content into something that can be passed as HttpContent to the post method, e.g.

```
            var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(url);
            var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
            var byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);
            byteContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
```

Then you will get a valid response.

Answer (score 1):

Use /image/ in the end of URL (Example: "https://....//detect/iterations/Iteration37/**image**/nostore")

[Example postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CukyF.png)
[Binary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcRhj.png)