# POST data using HttpClient

Tags: c#, json, httpclient, httpcontent

I'm trying to POST a data to web using HttpClient but i can't succeed.

Here is my JSON web api

```
{
    "Categories":[
        {
            "CategoryID":1,
            "Category":"Category 1"
        },
        {
            "CategoryID":2,
            "Category":"Category 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

i'am sending categories data to web my web developer send me above json to send a data from winform to web

Here is my code

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> paramt = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string,string>("CategoryID","1"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string,string>("Category","Pizza")
                };
                HttpContent q = new FormUrlEncodedContent(paramt);
                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", api);
                    HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("api/categories", q).Result;
 }
```

sorry for my english moderator please update my question

Comment: What is bytecontent? Also, why are you not using async await etc and... What is the problem? Please ask a proper question..

Comment: please see again and i want to send to data to web

Comment: You haven't described the problem. Also, I don't see any evidence of you converting your data to JSON. You're sending it as `FormUrlEncodedContent` which should set the content-type to `x-www-form-urlencoded` and create a body like `CategoryID=1&Category=Pizza` based on your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass an object to HttpClient.PostAsync and serialize as a JSON body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36625881/how-do-i-pass-an-object-to-httpclient-postasync-and-serialize-as-a-json-body)

Comment: Two things: 1. Only people whose names end with ♦ and whose profile says `(moderator)` are moderators. The rest of us are just users like yourself. 2. You haven't described the problem and why your code isn't working. You have only described what you're trying to do, not why you've posted a question. Despite this, I think I understand the issue, as I've described above. The linked duplicate shows you how to post JSON (as opposed to a form post) as you're currently doing.

Comment: {"CategoryID":1,"Category":"Category 1"}  my code works perfectly with this json only not working with nested json object like which i shown above

Comment: You are not posting JSON, you are posting a form body. You are not posting JSON, you are posting a form body. You are not posting JSON, you are posting a form body. You are not posting JSON, you are posting a form body. See the duplicate I linked, which shows how to post **JSON**.

Comment: Why am I saying you're not posting JSON? Because I've read your code.

Comment: StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Connection: keep-alive
  Keep-Alive: timeout=15
  X-RateLimit-Limit: 60
  X-RateLimit-Remaining: 58

Comment: yes m posting a form body

Comment: Then why do you say you're posting JSON?

Comment: because m working with web api first time

Comment: OK Well the duplicate will show you how to send JSON. Just follow that. Also note that if you serialize `paramt` to JSON at the moment, you'll get `[{"Key":"CategoryID","Value":"1"},{"Key":"Category","Value":"Pizza"}]`. An example of how to get the JSON you require can be seen [here](http://rextester.com/MEMN11145).

Comment: john thannnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnkkkkkkkkkkkkk youuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu this is working

Comment: post as a Answer i will mark for others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks [@John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3181933/john) with the help of yours i did this

```
public class CategoryItem
        {
            public int CategoryID { get; set; }
            public string Category { get; set; }
        }

        public class CategoriesRoot
        {
            public IList<CategoryItem> Categories { get; set; }
        }

         var tmp = new CategoriesRoot
                {
                    Categories = new List<CategoryItem> {
                    new CategoryItem { CategoryID = 1, Category = "Pizza" }
                }
                };

                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", api);
                    HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/categories", tmp).Result;
                    }
```