# Asp.NET Core Integration tests: POST method gets null values

Tags: c#, rest, testing, asp.net-core, integration-testing

I'm trying to test my .NET Core REST api using `WebClientFactory` method indicated in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.1#customize-the-client-with-withwebhostbuilder). When I test the `GET` method everything goes well, but I don't know why when I send data through a `PostAsync` method it arrives as `null`.

Here is the Test code:

```
public class TravelAgentEndToEndTest : IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory<Startup>>
{
    private readonly WebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory;
    private readonly HttpClient httpClient;

    public TravelAgentEndToEndTest(WebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory)
    {
        this.factory = factory;
        this.httpClient = factory.CreateClient();
    }



    [Fact]
    public async Task TravelAgentReceivesInvalidClientDataAndRejectsIt()
    {   
        string emptyClientData = "Bad";
        string url = "/api/clients";
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url,
            new StringContent(emptyClientData,Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));


        Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, response.StatusCode);
    }
}
```

the POST method in my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody]string value)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

When I debug the test I see that `value` is `null`.
Any idea where am I making a mistake?

PS1: I tried to test the post method using Postman and it works.

PS2: The Startup class is as Visual studio created it using Web Api template under Asp.NETCore web project

Comment: have you tried this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36625881/how-do-i-pass-an-object-to-httpclient-postasync-and-serialize-as-a-json-body

Comment: client is not sending valid JSON.

Comment: `string emptyClientData = "\"Bad\"";`