# How do I POST a simple POCO using HttpClient?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple DTO object that looks like the following:

```
public class InstructionComponents
    {
        public int ApplicationNumber { get; set; }
        public string FurtherComments { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to be able to send this object through a POST request to an API endpoint that uses ASP.NET MVC. However I want to make sure that the data is sent using the body of the request, and isn't just appended to the url like in a GET.

This is simple enough using get requests and can be achieved with the following code.

```
            var url = //endpoint url   
            using(var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                var response = httpClient.GetStringAsync(url).Result;
                return result;
            }
```

I know that I can serialise the object to a JSON string using a library, but then what do I do with the string?

Comment: Note that you should not be instantiating a new `HttpClient` instance for every request. See [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8), where it says, "HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once and re-used throughout the life of an application. Instantiating an HttpClient class for every request will exhaust the number of sockets available under heavy loads. This will result in SocketException errors."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass an object to HttpClient.PostAsync and serialize as a JSON body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36625881/how-do-i-pass-an-object-to-httpclient-postasync-and-serialize-as-a-json-body)

Answer (score 0):

This is an POST example maybe can useful:

```
 var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
       { "thing1", "hello" },
       { "thing2", "world" }
    };

    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

    var response = await client.PostAsync("http://www.example.com/recepticle.aspx", content);

    var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: I've seen this, but is there any way to encode a custom object instead of a dictionary?

Comment: use this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36625881/how-do-i-pass-an-object-to-httpclient-postasync-and-serialize-as-a-json-body

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to the extension method [PostAsJsonAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/hh944521%28v%3dvs.108%29)

This method will handle any serialization of the object that is necessary.

From the documentation it can be found

Namespace:   System.Net.Http
Assembly:  System.Net.Http.Formatting (in System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll)

Contrived example from the web:

```
static async Task<Uri> CreateProductAsync(Product product)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(
        "api/products", product);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    // return URI of the created resource.
    return response.Headers.Location;
}
```