# HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException

Tags: java, .net, spring, spring-boot, dotnet-httpclient

I have this class in my *.NET* application to send some data from client(.NET) to server(Spring) :

```
    class NetworkController
    {
        private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        public static async Task SendUserDataAsync()
        {
            var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "firstName", "sunny" },
                { "lastName", "leone" },
                { "timeStamp", "test" }
            };
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
            var response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:8080/user", content);
            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        }
    }
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4015346/10305444)

And in my Spring Boot application, I a class called `User` :

```
@Entity
public class User
{
    @Id
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String timeStamp;
    public User(){}
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "firstName : "+this.firstName + "\n"+"lastName : " + this.lastName;
    }
}
```

In my *rest-controller* I have this method to insert `User` :

```
@PostMapping("/user")
    User addUser(@RequestBody User user)
    {
        System.out.println(user);//this always prints an empty line, maybe receiving nothing
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }
```

I get this warning **Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported]**

I have created this class(with the concept of Spring) in .NET, but it seems no use :

```
class User
    {
        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        String timeStamp;

        public User()
        {
            firstName = "1"
            lastName = "2"
            timeStamp = "test"
        }

    }
```

Wouldn't sending an object instead of dictionary be more gentle and tidy ? How to do so ?

How can I resolve this problem ?

Comment: It seems that when a dictionary is sent it is not serialized as json. This answer suggests to use Json.NET in order to serialize objects to json -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36625881/how-do-i-pass-an-object-to-httpclient-postasync-and-serialize-as-a-json-body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your .NET application, the line `var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);` indicates that the request will have a HTTP header `Content-Type` set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

It means the data stored in `var values = new Dictionary...` will be formatted by .NET as a **query string** such as `firstName=sunny&lastName=leone&timeStamp=test`.

That is what your Sprint server receives. However it wants to receive **JSON data**, not a query string. So it complains.

In order to get rid of the miscommunication, your .NET application should send JSON data, such as 
`{"firstName": "sunny", "lastName": "leone", "timeStamp": "test"}`, 
as expected by the Spring server.

Here is an example code:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

object anonymousObject = new
{
    firstName = "sunny",
    lastName = "leone",
    timeStamp = "test"
};

string jsonContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(anonymousObject);

var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://127.0.0.1:8080/user");
request.Content = new StringContent(jsonContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

You need to install the package Newtonsoft.Json in order to call `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(anonymousObject)`, as pointed by [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36625881/how-do-i-pass-an-object-to-httpclient-postasync-and-serialize-as-a-json-body) mentionned by @alfcope.